# Node commissioning failed in MAAS for supermicro

Tags: maas, pxe

Just getting started with Maas. The supermicro server PXE booted but did not show up on the UI. So I tried to manually add and commission the node but that failed as well.

The following error on the server after PXE boot at the login:

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We also had issues deploying nodes - both turned out to be switch issues:

First issue was machine would boot via PXE, but had IPMI connectivity issues on MAAS server - ended up only half ports on original switch had POE.

With supermicro if you don't see the BMC  POST on booting for IPMI then the deployment will not work.

Make sure all ports on your switch support POE.

Our second issue was related to commission timeout - which was DHCP related. We changed setting on cisco switch to make dhcp pass through quicker:

spanning-tree portfast

Comment: Why would you need PoE for IPMI?